# What's the need for SQL Server Integration Services as service

Tags: ssis

I have a SQL Server box and I am wondering what's the need for me to install Integration Services.
I have some packages, some inside SQL Server and some others in the filesystem.
I can run those packages using

- DTExec Command Line Utility
- DTExecUI Windows Application
- SQL Server Agent

So the question : What do I need to install Integration Services in my box?
Thanks for your clarification

Answer (score 0):

I found this [link](http://www.ssistalk.com/2009/11/04/ssis-what-does-the-ssis-service-actually-do-anyway/)

It's said *"The SSIS Service, quite simply, is responsible for managing the Integration Services interface in SQL Server Management Studio. It enables the ability to import/export packages, view running packages, and view stored packages*
"